# Is there a way to expand a canvas Sukkah?

Tags: halacha, sukkot, sukkah, architecture-design

After playing around with ideas for seating in my Sukkah, I began to wonder, what if I just expanded it?  The problem is that it's made of canvas, which is wrapped around a metal frame.  This does not seem like it would be expandable.  But then I began to think about the possibility of pulling back one of the "walls" (ie., just not wrapping it around, and instead extending it out).  Below are some rough sketches of my current canvas Sukkah and my first rough idea of a way to expand it and open it up.

[image: Canvas Sukkah - Rough Sketch]

[image: Canvas Sukkah - Expanded, First Idea]

The idea is that I would just not wrap the canvas all the way around, and instead I'd extend it outward and set up posts to support the Sechach.  Some of the posts are needed for the structural integrity of the Sukkah frame itself, and so they won't be taken down, and I'd add new posts in a couple of spots to support additional "roof" beams with bamboo laid across the top of them.

So the theoretical side of my question is, how far can I extend the 3rd wall (the wall that's roughly 7 feet long) without a physical wall there?  It would have a Tzurath HaPethaḥ, if that makes a difference, all the way across, because I would still need beams to support the Sechach, and those posts are there to support the beams.  So, every place you see a gap, there would still be a beam over the top of that gap.

(I know the dimensions are off, but my computer graphic abilities are limited!)

On the practical side of my question, one issue of possible concern with my new design is that the tightly wrapped canvas might act like a sail and topple the Sukkah in a gust of wind. The frame is heavy and very sturdy, and the canvas itself is also heavy, but I wonder if it might still be a problem.  Another issue related to wind exposure is whether items on the table might be blown to the ground.

And, as I said, this is a first rough idea of one way to expand it, so if you have other suggestions that would work better, from either the standpoint of Halachah or practicality, I'm open to ideas, especially from those with real-world experience!

Comment: I assume you're not putting it near a building? That could solve any problems....

Comment: @msh210, I hadn't thought of that, but I think the overhang would cause too many problems.

Comment: I'm looking around and getting the sense that you can just extend it forever without even a tzurat hapetach because I can't find a limit. That's not such a good proof though.

Comment: Well, @double aa, remember that this is not the same as my other question. There, there's a gap in the wall. Here, the wall ends. The third wall. And there's no fourth wall. And I want to sit in the unwalled portion. Can the wall be extended virtually, either by means of the צורת הפתח, or simply by virtue of the fact that the rest of the Sukkah extends (or, another way of saying the latter could be, do you even need to be within the boundary of the Sukkah's third wall)?

Comment: ([This is the other question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19132/5) referenced in [the comment above](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20268/is-there-a-way-to-expand-a-canvas-sukkah#comment47764_20268)^^^.)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen someone extend his canvas Sukka by purchasing additional poles and canvas.

Comment: I appreciate the input, although it's not the creative solution I was looking for. Having said that, first of all, it was not my downvote, and second of all, sometimes the simplest solutions are the best solutions.

Comment: Have you got any input on the Halachic portion of my question?

Comment: When I answered I figured there may be some downvotes, however I felt it was an adequate solution to your problem.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Your answer is neither cheap, nor very creative, but it is rather straightforward and practical. +1

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Chayei Adam 145:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38644&pgnum=423)

[image: Image of Chayei Adam 145:3]

While four walls are ideal, if you have two walls that form a corner, and the third wall has at least a *tefach* (~4 inches) of width and forms a *tzuras hapesach*, that works.

(He continues on a discussion whether this is an adequate "private space" with regards to carrying on shabbos; basically if we call it good enough to be a sukkah, we call it good enough for carrying inside on shabbos -- at least the shabbos of sukkos --  but that's a different issue.)

Comment: I disagree that it is moot. For those who live in cities without Eiruvin (or don't hold of the Eiruvin) this issue is very significant as Shabbat of Sukkot is the one time of year when you most need to be able to carry outside.