# Why must a sukkah have three walls?

Tags: halacha, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, sukkah

Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh, Yalqut Yosef ([Orahh Hayim 630:1](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_30.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%9CB-B%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99B%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AAB%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94-%D7%90)) states:

> הסוכה צריכה להיעשות משלש דפנות וסכך
>
> [A] sukkah must be made of [a minimum of] three walls and *sekhakh*.

Why must a sukkah have three (or more) walls? Why is a structure built of two parallel walls insufficient to be a proper sukkah?

Comment: Are you asking "why does the definition of sukkah require that the structure have three walls", as in, how do we know that, or are you asking "why would God require people to sit in a structure of three walls"? If the former, see Maseches Sukkah 6b, but the 'taamei-mitzvot' tag indicates that you're asking the latter

Comment: Thank you for the Gemara citation! In truth, I'm looking for the latter (the ta'am) although I assumed that the former would lead to the latter.

Comment: Why not just one wall? Or just corner?

Answer (score 3):

I heard from the Rabbi of a shul I went to growing up (and it can be found in [Likkutei Torah](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/lkutey/37/79b) quoting Pri Etz Chaim)  that the Sukkah represents Hashem's watching over us, and therefore the Sukkah has the "form" of an arm giving a hug - 2 full walls and the third wall a tefach, corresponding to the two parts of an arm plus a hand, bent to wrap around those inside it.

Comment: What about when the two full walls are parallel? Consider my work of art here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/19133/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I think it still forms the same image through whatever Halachic realities are at play.

Comment: +1 - a source for this is [Likkutei Torah](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/adhaz/lkutey/37/79b) quoting the Pri Eitz Chaim.

Comment: @Yishai much appreciated, and edited in.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to have 2 walls and a small portion of a third, if it has Tzurat HaPetach.

The Yerushalmi learns this out from a Limmud of the Pasuk

" Isaiah 4:6:

There will be a sukkah that will serve as a shadow from the heat during the day, a place of refuge, and a cover from storm and from rain.

The Sages maintain that the verse refers to three different activities, and hence require three walls. Rabbi Shimeon counts "a cover from storm and from rain" as two different activities, and hence requires four walls." - http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/946097/jewish/Shofar-Sukkah-vLulav-Chapter-Four.htm

Alternatively, you would say that this is the minimum for an "enclosure" according to Halakah. Usually we assume that what works for Sukkah also works for defining the Reshuyot of Shabbat.